# Looking for algorithm to merge tuples containing duplicate fields, within list of tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I'm trying to find the best way to handle what on the surface appeared to be a simple task in python 2.7.

I have a list containing tuples.
Each tuple contains 2 dictionaries, each with 2 fields: 'alt', and 'id'.  'id' is always the same for every item in the list and be basically ignored for this question.

It looks something like this:

```
[
  ({id:1, alt: 10},{id:1, alt: 12}),
  ({id:1, alt: 8},{id:1, alt: 9}),
  ({id:1, alt: 9},{id:1, alt: 10})
]
```

Occasionally the value of the 'alt' field of the 1-index dictionary will be the same as the value of the 'alt' field of the 0-index dictionary of the next item in the list.  In the example above you can see that when alt = 9 in the 2nd and 3rd items in the list.

When this occurs, I want to merge those 2 tuples into a single tuple where the alt value of the 1-index dictionary of the first tuple would equal the alt value of the 1-index dictionary of the second tuple, effectively "canceling out" the duplicate alt values:

From this:

```
[
  ({id:1, alt: 8},{id:1, alt: 9}),
  ({id:1, alt: 9},{id:1, alt: 10})
]
```

to this:

```
[
  ({id:1, alt: 8},{id:1, alt: 10})
]
```

However there are times when this pattern occurs for multiple tuples in the list, and so the merge would need to occur across multiple tuples:

From this:

```
[
  ({id:1, alt: 8},{id:1, alt: 9}),
  ({id:1, alt: 9},{id:1, alt: 9}),
  ({id:1, alt: 9},{id:1, alt: 10}),
  ({id:1, alt: 10},{id:1, alt: 7}),
  ({id:1, alt: 8},{id:1, alt: 9}),
  ({id:1, alt: 9},{id: 1, alt: 10})
]
```

to this:

```
[
  ({id:1, alt: 8},{id:1, alt: 7}),
  ({id:1, alt: 8},{id:1, alt: 10})
]
```

I've tried several approaches and feel some sort of recursion is needed here but handling the latter case of needing to check consecutive tuples and merging across them is causing me to hit a wall.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def merge(xs):
    it = iter(xs)
    ret = next(it, (None, None))
    for x in it:
        if ret[1] is None or x[0]['alt'] != ret[1]['alt']:
            yield ret
            ret = x
        else:
            ret = ret[0], x[1]
    if ret[0] is not None:
        yield ret
```

Example:

```
>>> data = [
...     ({'id':1, 'alt': 8}, {'id':1, 'alt': 9}),
...     ({'id':1, 'alt': 9}, {'id':1, 'alt': 9}),
...     ({'id':1, 'alt': 9}, {'id':1, 'alt': 10}),
...     ({'id':1, 'alt': 10}, {'id':1, 'alt': 7}),
...     ({'id':1, 'alt': 8}, {'id':1, 'alt': 9}),
...     ({'id':1, 'alt': 9}, {'id': 1, 'alt': 10})
... ]
>>> list(merge(data))
[({'alt': 8, 'id': 1}, {'alt': 7, 'id': 1}),
 ({'alt': 8, 'id': 1}, {'alt': 10, 'id': 1})]

>>> data = [
...   ({'id':1, 'alt': 10}, {'id':1, 'alt': 12}),
...   ({'id':1, 'alt': 8}, {'id':1, 'alt': 9}),
...   ({'id':1, 'alt': 9}, {'id':1, 'alt': 10})
... ]
>>> list(merge(data))
[({'alt': 10, 'id': 1}, {'alt': 12, 'id': 1}),
 ({'alt': 8, 'id': 1}, {'alt': 10, 'id': 1})]

>>> list(merge([]))
[]
```